# PageDown with a Bootstrap 3 modal dialog, the background mask is causing many problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, pagedown

**Edit:**
*Check the bottom of this post for a solution, but now it introduces a new problem.*

I'm using the most recent version of PageDown with Bootstrap 3.

This series of events causes the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeChild' of null`

At which point the wmd-background mask is visible and over takes my page.

The error happens **after step 4**:

1. Open the custom modal dialog
2. Close the custom modal dialog (Using ok or cancel does not matter)
3. Open the custom modal dialog
4. Close the custom modal dialog (Using ok or cancel does not matter)

Here's the custom javascript code:

```
var insert_image = $("#insert-image");
var submit_image = $("#insert-image-submit");
var insert_image_close = $("#insert-image-close-x, #insert-image-close");

var file_url = $("#file_url", insert_image);
var file_local = $("#file_local", insert_image);

editor.hooks.set("insertImageDialog", function(callback) {
  submit_image.on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit image");
    insert_image.modal("hide");
    return callback(file_url.val().length > 0 ? file_url.val() : null);
  });
  insert_image_close.on("click", function() {
    console.log("cancel");
    return callback(null);
  });
  insert_image.modal("show");
  return true;
});

editor.run();
```

I did not see any solutions posted to this specific problem. I also tried hooking into Bootstrap's modal events and tried to either append my own or hide/show the wmd-background mask but I can't figure out a solution that results with no errors and has no extra background mask.

I should add too that I also have `data-backdrop=""` set in my html for when I build the modal dialog but this doesn't do anything other than prevent the background from being extra dark.

**Solution:**
I patched the library and changed:

Old broken version:
`background.parentNode.removeChild(background);`

New semi-working version:
`if (document.contains(background)) { background.parentNode.removeChild(background); }`

New problem:
The callback for both submit and cancel keep occurring more and more, as you open and close the form.

I get 1 then 2 then 4 then 6 then 10 console.log messages each time I close the form as I keep opening and closing it manually.

I fixed this temporarily by adding this to the top of the editor hook:

```
submit_image.unbind("click")
insert_image_close.unbind("click")
```

This seems like a hack, surely there's a better way to handle memoizing an event handler rather than unbind it + rebind it?